# Cannot get Array to print with extra spaces in front. Only the first value will print with spaces

Tags: c++, arrays, string

What do I need to do to get my array values to print with a tab or spaces in front?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const char FIELD_DELIM_CHAR = ',';
const char LINE_DELIM_CHAR  = '\n';
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 1000;
int fileLen;

string city[ARRAY_SIZE];
char buff1[ARRAY_SIZE];
double lowTemp[ARRAY_SIZE];
double highTemp[ARRAY_SIZE];

int LoadData();
void ShowAll();
int ShowCities(string city[], string str);
void ConvertStringToLowerCase(const string orig, string& lwr);

int i, count;
string filePath;
ifstream inFile;
```

Here's my main program

```
void main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to Josh's Library Database. " << endl << endl;

    char action;
    string str;
    int data;
```

My issues are with the output results of S and F. I'm getting the correct output values, but can't get them to be tabbed over or include extra spaces in the beginning

```
    do
    {
        cout << "(L)oad File,  (S)how All,  (F)ind City, (Q)uit:";
        cin >> action;
        action = tolower(action);

        if(action == 'l')
        {
            cout << "Please enter the name of the temperatures file: ";
            cin >> filePath;
            data = LoadData();

            if(data <= 0) // Prompt user to retry if filepath entered has no values
            {
                cout << "Error opening file!  Please try again! " << endl << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << data << " record(s) found." << endl << endl;
            }
        }
        else if(action == 's')
        {
            ShowAll();
        }
        else if(action == 'f')
        {
            cout << ShowCities(city, str) << " record(s) found. " << endl << endl;
        }
        else if(action == 'q')
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid Response! Please try again! " << endl << endl;
        }
    }while(action != 'q');  
}

int LoadData()
{
    char chr;
    int i = 0;

    // Open the file
    inFile.open(filePath);

    while (!inFile.eof())
    {
        buff1[0] = 0;

        // Get the next field from the file
        inFile.getline(buff1, ARRAY_SIZE, FIELD_DELIM_CHAR);

        // If the array is empty, exit the loop
        if (buff1[0] == 0)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if(inFile.eof())
        {
            return i;
        }
        else
        {
            // Convert 'buff' char values into a string
            string s(buff1);
            city[i] = s;

            // Collect low temp value, ignore comma, collect high temp value
            inFile >> lowTemp[i];
            inFile.get(chr);
            inFile >> highTemp[i];
        }
        i++;
    } 

    if (inFile.is_open())
    {   //  Close the file in such a way that it can be reopened
        inFile.close();
        inFile.clear(std::ios_base::goodbit);
    } 
    return i; // Return total number of cities listed
}
```

This is where I'm having a lot of problems, the output only adds the extra spaces to the first city listed, but not to any of the rest

```
// Loop to display all data in files
void ShowAll()
{
    for(int i = 0; city[i] != ""; i++)
    {
        cout << "   " << city[i] << " (" << lowTemp[i] << ", " << highTemp[i] << ")";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}
```

When I pick this option, the outputs don't include the extra spaces and it drops down to the next line before outputting the first city, which it shouldn't.

```
int ShowCities(string city[], string str)
{
    string lwr1, lwr2;
    int idx, count = 0;

    cout << "City: ";
    cin >> str;

    // Convert a copy of the search string to lower case
    ConvertStringToLowerCase(str, lwr1);

    for (int i = 0; city[i] != ""; i++)
    {
        // Convert a copy of the array string to lower case
        ConvertStringToLowerCase(city[i], lwr2);

        idx = lwr2.find(lwr1);
        if (idx > -1)
        {
            cout << "   " << city[i] << " (" << lowTemp[i] << ", " << highTemp[i] << ")";
            count++;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    return count; // Return total number of cities with matching strings
}

void ConvertStringToLowerCase(const string orig, string& lwr)
{
    lwr = orig;
    for (int j = 0; j < orig.length(); ++j)
    {
        lwr[j] = tolower(orig.at(j));
    }
}


/*
*/ This is the data from the inFile.

Katmandu,       -34,  28
Perth,           92,  105
Chicago,         22,  45
St. Petersburg,  19,  37
Miami,           68,  84
Cincinnati,      21,  39
Bern,            45,  55
Johannesburg,    87,  102
Seattle,         34,  42
New York,        24,  39
St. Louis,       12,  23
Beijing,         45,  66
Munich,          31,  38
Zurich,          33,  41
Buenos Aires,    69,  84


Output for ShowAll() is: Only the first output includes spaces.

   Katmandu,       -34,  28
Perth,           92,  105
Chicago,         22,  45
St. Petersburg,  19,  37
Miami,           68,  84
Cincinnati,      21,  39
Bern,            45,  55
Johannesburg,    87,  102
Seattle,         34,  42
New York,        24,  39
St. Louis,       12,  23
Beijing,         45,  66
Munich,          31,  38
Zurich,          33,  41
Buenos Aires,    69,  84
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a result of word-wrapping since there are no newlines. Just add an `endl` at the end of the line:

```
cout << "   " << city[i] << " (" << lowTemp[i] << ", " << highTemp[i] << ")" << endl;
```

Edit:

```
const char FIELD_DELIM_CHAR = ',';
...
inFile.getline(buff1, ARRAY_SIZE, FIELD_DELIM_CHAR);
```

This is causing your code to read in the newline character before the city. Thus, when you output `city[i]` it is preceded by a newline, causing it to show up at the beginning of a newline.

You need to read in your data taking this into consideration, or trim this extra whitespace off once you have read it in.

Comment: I've tried that.  That causes it to put a empty line between each output, and it still only adds the spaces to the first output.

Comment: That gives a clue - there is an extra newline somewhere. Perhaps it is the first character of `city[i]`? Since Katmandu is first in the input file, it is not preceded by a newline, so it doesn't display in the output.

Comment: Yeah it seems that when comparing the strings, if the string doesn't match part of Katmandu, it will add the empty line, but if it is within Katmandu, then it doesn't skip to the next line. It still only puts the spaces in front of Katmandu, though, instead of in front of every city.

Comment: The spaces are there - they are the blank lines that you see. There is a newline at or near the beginning of `city[i]`, causing it to print on its own at the next line.

Comment: This line `inFile.getline(buff1, ARRAY_SIZE, FIELD_DELIM_CHAR);` is causing you to read the newlines into the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction.  I couldn't get rid of that line, but I fixed the issue by changing how I collected the temperature values by doing this:
    inFile.getline(buff, ARRAY_SIZE, FIELD_DELIM_CHAR);
    lowTemp[i] = atof(buff);
    inFile.getline(buff, ARRAY_SIZE, LINE_DELIM_CHAR);
    highTemp[i] = atof(buff);